# Maven parent from dependencies

Tags: java, maven, parent-pom

I have an acceptance test module that I would like to run on Docker. To get this working, I had to copy all its parent poms, until the very last one. I would like to find out if it is possible to use a parent pom from a dependency, as in having something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact.id.parent</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

would make Maven find the parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact.id.parent</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Assuming that the acceptance test module version is also `x.x.x-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: @Tunaki, It seems the link you posted is around evaluating the placeholder or the version variable which is not my issue. Just to rephrase my question, is it possible to use a parent pom from a dependency you pull from the repository?

Comment: Ha, I misunderstood then. It is unclear for me what you're asking then. You can use any parent you want as long as you have its coordinate and its packaging is pom.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. My understanding is that the parent pom will be evaluated before any dependencies. This allows you to use variables defined in the parent in your dependencies, which would be impossible in the situation you describe

Comment: @ewanc : just curious, is it even possible with `<dependency>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact.id.parent</artifactId>
    <version>"some older stable version"</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>` ??

Comment: I'm struggling to find any documentation just now but I don't think that's valid syntax.